# How to compress hdf5 file when resizing?

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

Here is my code:

```
n = 100000       #This is what makes it tricky - lots of files going into this hdf5 file

with h5py.File('image1.h5','w') as f:
    dset_X = f.create_dataset('X',(1,960,224,224),maxshape=(None,960,224,224),chunks=True,compression='gzip')
    dset_y = f.create_dataset('y',(1,112,224*224),maxshape=(None,112,224*224),chunks=True,compression='gzip')
    n_images = 0
    for fl in files[:n]:
        X_chunk,y_chunk = get_arrays(fl)
        dset_X.resize(n_images+1,axis=0)
        dset_y.resize(n_images+1,axis=0)
        print dset_X.shape,dset_y.shape
        dset_X[n_images:n_images+1,:,:,:]=X_chunk
        dset_y[n_images:n_images+1,:,:]=y_chunk
        n_images+=1
```

This works fine and dandy. However, with 1 file, the size of the hdf5 is 6.7MB. With 2 files its 37MB ( should be 12 MB right?). With 10 its all the way up to 388MB (should be 67 right?)

So clearly adding the compression flag to the end of the 2nd and third line isn't working as intended. How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: have you checked the `compression` attribute of your datasets before and after you resize them?

Comment: yes, it continues to say: gzip when I print dset_X.compression or dset_y.compression at each step in the loop

Comment: you could try to save the data to disk, and see what's in it, and if it can be compressed again with gzip. If size is reduced drastically, time for a bug report to hdf5 team.

Comment: How do you get to 6.7 MB? My guess is that (960+112)*224*224 / 8 = 6723584. I divide by 8 because I assume you have one bit per pixel. This would mean that your image consists of monochrome black-white pixels. Is this true? If not, what is your data type?

Comment: Also please post your `get_arrays` function. Even better, make an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can just copy-paste-execute to reproduce your issue. Use random data if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this successfully using pytables.

```
def get_arrays(each_file):
    lab = color.rgb2lab(io.imread(each_file))
    X = lab[:,:,:1]
    y = lab[:,:,1:]
    X_rows,X_columns,X_channels=X.shape
    y_rows,y_columns,y_channels=y.shape
    X_channels_first = np.transpose(X,(2,0,1))
    X_sample = np.expand_dims(X_channels_first,axis=0)
    X_3d = np.tile(X_sample,(1,3,1,1))
    X_3d_scaled = X_3d * 255.0/X_3d.max()
    hc = extract_hypercolumn(model,[3,8,15,22],X_3d_scaled)
    hc_scaled = (hc -hc.min())/(hc.max()-hc.min())
    print hc_scaled.max(),hc_scaled.min()
    hc_expand_dims = np.expand_dims(hc_scaled,axis=0)
    y_reshaped = np.reshape(y,(y_rows*y_columns,y_channels))
    classed_pixels_first = KNN.predict_proba(y_reshaped)
    classed_classes_first = np.transpose(classed_pixels_first,(1,0))
    classed_expand_dims = np.expand_dims(classed_classes_first,axis=0)
    print "hypercolumn shape: ",hc_expand_dims.shape,"classified output color shape: ",classed_expand_dims.shape
    return hc_expand_dims,classed_expand_dims 

filters = tables.Filters(complevel=5, complib='zlib')

with tables.openFile('raw.h5','w') as f:
#    filters = tables.Filters(complib='blosc', complevel=5)
    dset_X = f.create_earray(f.root, 'X', tables.Atom.from_dtype(np.dtype('Float64')), (0,960,224,224),filters=filters)
    dset_y = f.create_earray(f.root, 'y', tables.Atom.from_dtype(np.dtype('Float64')), (0,112,224*224),filters=filters)
    for fl in files[0:12000]:
        X_chunk,y_chunk=get_arrays(fl)
        dset_X.append(X_chunk)
        dset_y.append(y_chunk)
```